# Drools: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.eclipse.sisu.Parameters is not a binding annotation

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am getting this error when I am trying to execute my Drools project. I am using version `7.73.0.Final`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.eclipse.sisu.Parameters is not a binding annotation. Please annotate it with @BindingAnnotation.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:120) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.inject.Key.ensureIsBindingAnnotation(Key.java:402) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:389) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:251) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:28) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.<init>(DependencyAnalyzer.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<init>(ElementAnalyzer.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.<init>(PlexusComponentProvider.java:37) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildComponentProvider(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:57) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:91) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34) ~[na:na]
    at org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:594) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:152) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:192) ~[na:na]
```

It occurs when calling `buildAll()` on `KieBuilder` object.

Relevant code:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

kfs.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(new File(drlPath)));

KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);

kb.buildAll();
if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR))
   throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kb.getResults().toString());

KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());

KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests a library incompatibility between Guice and Sisu. You can try to use the Guice and Sisu versions shown in the Sisu documentation: https://eclipse.github.io/sisu.inject/#code

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.sisu</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.sisu.inject</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```